# Using C++ library functions from Python

Tags: c++, python, windows, dll, pyqt4

I got a library created for Win x86 with MS Visual Studio 2010. 
And I can not change the content of a library to use Boost.Python.

I'm using Python 3.3 with PyQt4 to create interface, but not restricted to these versions.  I need to call functions and get objects from said C++ library. What is the easiest way to wrap C++ library to be called from python?

I guess, that such question was already asked, but I can not seem to find it.

Here's an example of header file:

```
namespace SDK 
{
    class IMethod 
    {
    public:
        virtual IModel* CreateModel(const IBuffer* pBuffer, const char* text) = 0;
    };

    extern __declspec(dllexport) SDK::IMethod* CreateMethod(MethodID integer);
}
```

Comment: SWIG is one way. Write a Python extension is another.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the point is that I can not find examples of how to do this. Could you please provide some?

By the way, I guess that writing this project in C++/Qt would be easier, may be I'll try this.

Comment: There are countless examples of SWIG and Python extension writing.